# How to pass arguments for return redirect(url()) in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to update the profile in flask. Everything working fine but once its edited msg is not displaying in html page when i give {{ msg11 }}. I'm not getting how to pass the arguments so that the msg will be displayed in html page. I tried this approach but its not displaying in html page

```
@app.route("/updateProfile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def updateProfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        firstName = request.form['firstName']
        lastName = request.form['lastName']
        with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as con:
                try:
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    cur.execute('UPDATE users SET firstName = ?, lastName = ? WHERE email = ?', (firstName, lastName))
                    con.commit()
                    msg11 = "Saved Successfully"
                except:
                    con.rollback()
                    msg11 = "Error occured"
        con.close()
        return redirect(url_for('editProfile', msg11=msg11))
```

Adding editprofile function. I have removed sql queries in this function

```
def editProfile():
    if 'email' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('root'))
    loggedIn, firstName, noOfItems = getLoginDetails()

        profileData = cur.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return render_template("editProfile.html", profileData=profileData, loggedIn=loggedIn, firstName=firstName, noOfItems=noOfItems)
```

Comment: Where's the editProfile function?

Comment: @IainShelvington added editProfile function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide keyword arguments to the `url_for` function, Flask automatically encodes your values into URI components and appends them to your request url.

Using your code as an example, doing this

```py
msg11='Saved Successfully'
return redirect(url_for('editProfile', msg11=msg11))
```

Will yield this URL when passed to the `editProfile` route

```
/editProfile?msg11=Saved+Successfully
```

You can easily extract this value using Flask's built-in `request` object

```py
from flask import request
# Inside of editProfile() route
msg11 = request.args.get('msg11', None)
```

That way, you can simply check if this value exists (calling `get()` is the same as the usual Python convention where a value of `None` will be returned if the value is not found) and pass it along to your HTML template.

Furthermore, using Jinja's functionality you can display the message only if it is not a `None` value by using something like this

```html
{% if msg11 is not none %}
<h1>{{ msg11 }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

---

A complete minimum example is outline below

`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/updateProfile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def updateProfile():
    msg11 = "Saved Successfully"
    return redirect(url_for("editProfile", msg11=msg11))

@app.route("/editProfile")
def editProfile():
    msg11 = request.args.get("msg11")
    return render_template("editProfile.html", msg11=msg11)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`templates/editProfile.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>editProfile</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if msg11 is not none %}
    <h1>{{ msg11 }}</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>msg11 has a value of None</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It gave an error AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'. So i tried request.args.get my url became like this /editProfile?msg11=Saved+Successfully

Comment: Yes @error_ab you are entirely correct, I should have caught that before publishing.

Comment: Is there any other way to display the msg in html page??@vulpxn

Comment: If you mean without setting the conditional, you can always just choose to display `msg11` no matter what, you will just see a `null` or `None` printed in your interface, but that is beyond the scope of the question as asked.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the complete minimum example which I was able to get this to work under, take a look at that.